# How do I set a proxy for WebSocketLink uri

Tags: reactjs, heroku, websocket, react-apollo, apollo-client

I want to deploy my react app to Heroku but I don't know how to set a proxy in setupProxy.js for a web socket or will it work if I do not set the proxy?

I have tried

```
const wsLink = new WebSocketLink({
  uri: "/subscriptions",
  options: {
    reconnect: true,
    connectionParams: {
      authToken: localStorage.getItem(AUTH_TOKEN)
    }
  }
});

in index.js and 

  app.use(
      "subscriptions",
      proxy({
        target: "ws://localhost:4000",
        changeOrigin: true,
        ws: true
      })
    );
in setupProxy.js but it doesn't work


const wsLink = new WebSocketLink({
  uri: "ws://localhost:4000/subscriptions",
  options: {
    reconnect: true,
    connectionParams: {
      authToken: localStorage.getItem(AUTH_TOKEN)
    }
  }
});
```